# ReactJS How to pass a prop to a component in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function App() {
   const [currentPanel, setCurrentPanel] = useState(ProfilePanel); // ProfilePanel is a component
     return (
          <div className={styles.App}>
                    {currentPanel}     
          </div>
     );
}
```

In code i set the component "ProfilePanel" to a "curentPanlel" state, then in App i change the component in state, and this render an another panel. the problem is that i dont know how to pass props when i render it like this.
i tried the `{currentPanel()}` but is return an error.
please help to find a method to solve this, or if this method to render a component in state are absolutly wrong tell how to do this another way.

Comment: Don't add a component to state. Import the component. Set the state to the panel id that you need and then update the JSX when that state is changed.

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You've got problem X, you think storing a component in state will help you solve it, but now you're having trouble doing that (Y). You're likely to be better off solving `X` a different way. You might want to post a (different) question describing problem X and asking how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that i dont know how to pass props when i render it like this

You'd do it by using an initial capital letter for the state member (`CurrentPanel` instead of `currentPanel`), and then using it as normal (`<CurrentPanel someProp="some value" />`). (It has to be initially-capped because that's how JSX knows it's supposed to be a component, not a tag name.) **But**, you'll struggle to set a different component function in state, because component functions are, well, functions, and when you pass a function to a state setter, it thinks you're using the callback version of the state setter and calls your function, rather than setting it in state.

If you absolutely **have** to hold a component function in state, wrap it in an object, but it's much more likely that there's a better solution to the overall problem you're trying to solve.